# Проблема со скриптом игры

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Суть такова, что игрок, когда получает урон начинает бежать быстрее и подключается анимация бега, но, если игрок просто встанет и его будут атаковать, то игрок поворачивается в сторону второго игрока, который его бьет и начинает бежать на месте. **Вопрос, как это устранить?** Пробовал через нейросеть, ничего не вышло. Скрипт ниже -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // константы для имен анимаций
    const string IDLE = "m_idle_A";
    const string WALK = "m_run";
    const string DEATH = "m_death_A";

    // ссылки на компоненты
    CustomAction input;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator animator;
    private Animator playerAnimator;

    // настройки движения
    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem clickEffect; 
    [SerializeField] LayerMask clickableLayers;   

    // настройки ускорения
    [Header("Speed Boost")]
    [SerializeField] float speedBoost = 2.0f;        // цвеличение скорости
    [SerializeField] float maxBoostDuration = 7.0f;  // максимальная длительность ускорения
    private float initialSpeed;                    // исходная скорость
    private bool isBoosting;                       // флаг ускорения
    private float boostDuration;                   // длительность ускорения

    // настройки здоровья
    [Header("Health")]
    [SerializeField] int maxHealth = 3; 
    private int currentHealth;         
    [SerializeField] Text hpText;      
    [SerializeField] Button restartButton; 


    [SerializeField] float lookRotationSpeed = 8.0f; 

    
    private bool isRunning = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        
        input = new CustomAction();
        AssignInputs();
    }

    void AssignInputs()
    {
        
        input.Main.Move.performed += ctx => ClickToMove();
    }

    void ClickToMove()
    {
        
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100, clickableLayers))
        {
            agent.destination = hit.point;

            if (clickEffect != null)
            {
                Instantiate(clickEffect, hit.point + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), clickEffect.transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        input.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        input.Disable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        UpdateHPText();
        restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        initialSpeed = agent.speed;
        isBoosting = false;
        boostDuration = 0f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        FaceTarget();
        SetAnimations();

        if (isRunning)
        {
            animator.Play(WALK);
        }

        if (isBoosting)
        {
            boostDuration -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (boostDuration <= 0f)
            {
                isBoosting = false;
                SetSpeed(initialSpeed);
            }
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            playerAnimator.Play(DEATH);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void FaceTarget()
    {
        // поворот к цели
        Vector3 direction = agent.destination - transform.position;

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * lookRotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    void SetAnimations()
    {
        if (agent.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            
            animator.Play(IDLE);
            isRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Hunter"))
        {
            if (currentHealth > 0)
            {
                currentHealth--;
                UpdateHPText();
                ApplySpeedBoost();
            }

            if (currentHealth == 0)
            {
                restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        if (other.CompareTag("WinLine"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Вы победили!");
        }
    }

    public void ApplySpeedBoost()
    {
        isBoosting = true;
        boostDuration = maxBoostDuration;
        SetSpeed(initialSpeed + speedBoost);
    }

    private void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        agent.speed = speed;
    }

    private void UpdateHPText()
    {
        hpText.text = "HP: " + currentHealth;
    }
}
```